# Custom nuget package for multiple versions of .Net core side by side

Tags: .net, nuget-package

I have two projects that when they build they generate respectively 2 nuget packages.

The thing is that they were built on .Net core 3.1, and now we would like to add some stuff but want to target for .Net 6.

We've already tried the framework update and there are no breaking changes on these libs which is good.

But the doubt is: if we push the framework upgrade to 6, Will other already existant projects running on .Net core 3.1 still build when getting new package upgrade or do we need to have any special care on this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Can you target your packages to .netstandart?

Comment: Hum pretty sure I can't at this stage. Anyway I ended up having multiple target frameworks on csproj and is working like a charm